# Rails - How to use TRY for nested records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following:

```
:caption => thread.thread_widgets.first.widgetable.title
```

That works fine if the thread has a thread_widget, which is optional. Given it's optional, if the thread has no thread_widgets, then this errors with

```
undefined method `widgetable' for nil:NilClass
```

Is there a way I can use try() so that the error doesn't kill the page?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:caption => (o = thread.thread_widgets.first) && o.widgetable.title
```

But you asked for `Object#try,` so:

```
:caption => thread.thread_widgets.first.try(:widgetable).try(:title)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another better option is to use the **Safe Navigation Operator** `&.` as follow:

```
:caption => thread.thread_widgets.first&.widgetable&.title
```

**Reference:**
http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/